# What's the difference between application- and router level- middleware when routing in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

In the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html), it says:

> Application level middleware are bound to an instance of express, using app.use() and app.VERB().
>
> Router level middleware work just like application level middleware except they are bound to an instance of `express.Router()`. The middleware system created at the application level in the example above, can be replicated at the router level using the following code.

In the app provided by the Express generator, I see in the main `app.js`, there is:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
```

And in `./routes/index.js`, I see this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

What is the purpose of `app.use` passing it to `router.get` instead of simply using `app.get`? And generally, what's the difference between `app.VERB` and `router.VERB` in terms of routing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> What is the purpose of app.use passing it to router.get instead of simply using app.get?

This is all just designing for modularity. It allows an application to be divided into several smaller loosely-coupled pieces and because they all do not have any direct knowledge of the shared `app` instance that combines them together, the modularity is achieved.

For example, you could build a whole user account subsystem that handles sign up, login, forgot password, etc, and share it between several different applications by "mounting" it within them via `app.use(require("my-user-system"))`.

That's the only purpose behind this. There no functional, technical, or performance difference otherwise.

> And generally, what's the difference between app.VERB and router.VERB in terms of routing?

No difference. The app has it's own main/primary router and `app.VERB` is just convenience sugar for the equivalent of `app.router.VERB`.

Comment: So `express.Router()` and `app = express()` will be the same object?

Comment: @MichaelHirschler nope. Usually, you have one app but several routers.

Answer (score 15):

An example will help here:

In the birds.js:

```
// birds.js

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
    next();
});
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Birds home page');
});
```

In the app.js:

```
// app.js

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var birds = require('./birds');
app.use('/birds', birds);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('app listening on port 3000!\naccess http://localhost:3000/birds/'))
```

Now requests to http://localhost:3000/birds/ will go to birds.js file.

This modular approach will make easy to maintain a large code base, as the application grows big.

Source: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 4):

Application has the method *listen* and some other which router doesn't have.

Application "does" the main thing, while route only groups some routes, provides encapsulation (see Manohar's answer with example).

Routes in router doesn't necessarily know in advance what will be its full route. See in the example that '/birds' is defined in app.js which is root for router in birds.js ... difference between app.VERB and rourer.VERB is in the context.